How to fetch the AWS Image that is over 7 days old?
I use the following Terraform code snippet to fetch the latest image. However, I have a requirement: the image must be 7 days old. If the latest image is not 7 days old, I must fetch the previous image.
How to do that?
  recipe = {
    description       = "description"
    parent_image_arn  = "arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-east-1:aws:image/amazon-linux-2-x86/x.x.x"
    working_directory = "/tmp"
  }



What aws resource are you using?

@ChrisDoyle,
The resource is EC2. I hope I understand your question.

You can use data blocks to look up AMI's that meet your criteria. This works by setting the before date as 7 days before now. Then searching for a list of AMI's using a filter and returning then in creation date order.
We then look up the details for each AMI. We compare the creation date for each AMI to the before date we are interested in and keep only those that are before our date.
Since this is a sorted list by date we can take the first item which will be the latest date which is before the date we specified
locals {
  # Set the date as 7 days ago
  ami_before_date = timeadd(timestamp(), "-168h") 

  # Loop through all the AMI's and return only those with a creation date before ours
  valid_amis = [for ami in data.aws_ami.ami_data: ami.arn if timecmp(ami.creation_date, local.ami_before_date) == -1]

  # Since this is a sorted list the first item is the latest valid ami
  latest_ami_before_date = local.valid_amis[0]
}

# Get all AMI's that meet our criteria
data "aws_ami_ids" "potential_amis" {
  owners = ["123456789012"]
  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["*Windows_Server-2022-English-Full-Base*"]
  }
  sort_ascending = true
}

# Lookup the details of each AMI
data "aws_ami" "ami_data" {
  count = length(data.aws_ami_ids.potential_amis.ids)
  filter {
    name = "image-id"
    values = [data.aws_ami_ids.potential_amis.ids[count.index]]
  }
}

output "latest_ami_before_date" {
  value = local.latest_ami_before_date
}


your solution works great if sort_ascending  is removed. It gives the ami, but I need an arn.

I need an ARN like this : arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-east-1:aws:image/amazon-linux-2-x86/2024.10.31

The data look up gets all the attributes for each AMI so if you want the ARN instead of the ID then just change the attribute from ami.id to ami.arn. I have updated the example

If your not using sort_ascending I am not sure you can be guaranteed the order of the results so just be careful if removing it.

you can do that using a python code in an external resource:
data "external" "image_arn" {
  program = ["python3", "filter_image.py"]
}

the filter_image.py will check all the images, order them by date, if the newest one is not older than 7 days, it will return for you the previous one, for example like this return {"image_arn": eligible_images[0]['arn']}
then you can easily access the arn using the data resource
output "image_arn" {
  value = data.external.image_arn.result["image_arn"]
}

or you can even use external data resource with a simpler CMD
resource "null_resource" "validate_image" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      aws imagebuilder list-images --region us-east-1 --query \
      'imageVersionList[?dateCreated<=`$(date -d "-7 days" -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)`].imageArn' \
      --output text
    EOT
  }
}

less code and easier to handle
